# EXCEPCIONES [PL/SQL]

Tags: oracle, plsql

Mis dudas:

1. ¿Como puedo controlar la excepción de una entrada vacía? (Explicación a continuación)
2. ¿Que valor se guarda en la variable si se da una entrada vacía?

He creado la variable:

```
DECLARE

v_entrada NUMBER(8) := &entrada;
```

No le doy un valor, es decir en el POPUP le doy a aceptar directamente, sin escribir.

### [PopUp al que me refiero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxGVA.png)

Al leer el código de error que dejaré entero al final, me encontré con esta linea

**PLS-00103: Se ha encontrado el símbolo ";" cuando se esperaba uno de los siguientes:**

así que pensé en controlar la excepción creando un if  comparando mi variable a " ; ", como podréis ver en el código sin éxito.

```
BEGIN

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_codigo);

    IF(v_codigo = ';')THEN

          RAISE v_excepcion;

    END IF;

EXCEPTION

    when v_excepcion then 

         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE('No has insertado un valor válido');
END;
```

**Error code**

```
Informe de error -
ORA-06550: línea 2, columna 32:
PLS-00103: Se ha encontrado el símbolo ";" cuando se esperaba uno de los siguientes:

   ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
   continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
   sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
   date <a string literal with character set specification>
   <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
   <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>
   <an al
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Answer (score 0):

**Al final pude resolver mi duda**

Las excepciones son para errores encontrados durante le ejecucion de mi función,proceso o bloque anónimo. no controlan errores de syntax - donde la función o proceso ni compilará.

Yo estaba usando una variable de substitucion, esta misma es substituida(reemplazada) por mi editor, ANTES de que el código llegue  al parser de PL/SQL, este tipo de errores no puedes ser anticipados y controlados en el codigo, si tu devuelves nada( Un string vacío), cuando se solicita, el mismo codigo recibirá nada, en ese lugar, y entonces la syntax de tu función o proceso será incorrecta. Tu variable lucirá tal que así después de todo el procedimiento explicado

`v_input NUMBER(8) := ;`

Y esto obviamente te devuelve error y es donde se encontraría el error que mencionaba.

**¿Entonces como compruebo una variable en el mismo tiempo de ejecución?**

La forma correcta sería usando parametros, o **bind variables** en un bloque anónimo.

La variable tiene que estar declarada e inicializada antes de ejecutar el bloque, en un command line como sql*plus , o en un GUI como toad o sql developer, se le pedirá un valor para la variable de enlace, en caso de que en esta ventana dejes el valor sin insertar se te contara como null el cual es perfectamente válido, pero eso es lo que quieres? , esa es otra cuestión)

el código tendrá que ser así :

```
    declare
  v_input number(8) := :entry;     --  notice the leading colon  :
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(v_input);
end;
/
```

En caso de que la persona que esté leyendo esto quiera controlar un caso nulo el código sería :

```
 declare
  v_input number(8) := :entry;
begin
  if v_input is null then
     --  handle it here
  else
     dbms_output.put_line(v_input);   -- or whatever else you need to do
  end if;
end;
/
```

Fuente de la información @mathguy

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60802272/exception-pl-sql

Comment: Sería mejor el añadir la fuente de consulta y no solo su nombre